# Angular how to refresh site after deploy updates?

Tags: angular, express, pm2

I am using angular 10 + pwa , so everything is caching. Server works with pm2.

The problem is that I update website a lot, every few days and sometimes after the update, user still sees old view in the client side which allows errors to appear.

1. My first approach was to use angular hashing - main.js -> main.864868684684.js , but thats not really working for me, because i can't tell pm2 to load a different file each time.
2. Then i disabled caching in my express server which runs the website, but then all caching is disabled, so this is bad too.

I am looking for a best approach, where my users could always see the newest version of my website + caching would work normally.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: are you using service worker added by ng add @angular/pwa?

Comment: yes,  "@angular/pwa": "^0.901.8"

Comment: You have to add a "version" tag to your ngsw-config.json

Comment: Please try to answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

First add a **version** tag to your ngsw-config.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "version": 327, /* Increment this on each publish */
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "/manifest.webmanifest"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "urls": [ /* Specify the api-calls/view that should be cached */
        "/web/**",
        "!/web/Account/**",
        "!/web/v1/Account/**",
        "!/web/v2/Account/**",
        "!/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 20,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "amp",
      "urls": [
        "/amp/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 20,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "account",
      "urls": [
        "/web/Account/**",
        "/web/v1/Account/**",
        "/web/v2/Account/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "external-callback",
      "urls": [ "/signin-microsoft", "/signin-google", "/signin-facebook", "/signin-twitter" ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sitemap",
      "urls": [
        "/Sitemap",
        "/Sitemap/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ],
  "navigationUrls": [
    /* Specify what links should/should be handled by your angular app/index-file */
    "/**",
    "!/**/*.*",
    "!/**/*__*",
    "!/**/*__*/**",
    "!/web/v2/Account/connect/**/**",
    "!/web/v2/Account/add/**/**",
    "!/api/**"
  ],
  "cacheConfig": {
    "strategy": "freshness"
  }
}
```

I then added the following code to check for new versions:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    //#region Check for updates
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      console.log('Updates enabled');
      this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe((upd) => {
        console.log('Update activated');
        window.location.reload();
      });
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe((upd) => {
        console.log('Update available');
        if (confirm('Do you want to install the new version of the app?')) {
          console.log('Activating update');
          this.swUpdate.activateUpdate();
        }
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
      this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
        console.log('Checking for updates');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Could not check for app updates', error);
      });
    }
    //#endregion
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
}
```

You're using @angular/pwa.
But anyway, now each time you publish a new version the application will check if the online version is more recent than the cached one...

I've used a `confirm` prompt before instlaling the update, but you may want to omit this, or handle this differently.

Comment: Property "version" is not allowed when i write it in ngsw-config.json

Comment: What angular version are you using? I'm using 9.1 and for me it works as expected... https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L4

Comment: 10 version, i dont get any error, but when i write it , it shows as a tooltip and a yellow border below that "property version is not allowed". 

And one one thing, where do you use version in your code ?

Comment: I don't need to use the version in my code, but this tells `@angular/pwa` that the javascript code needs to be pulled from the server again...

Comment: I just created a new app (angular 11.0.5) and added `@angular/pwa` and I'm able to run `ng build`. That's actually the most important

Comment: this.swUpdate.activated is deprecated.